# Glyphicon-calendar и получение дат из него в php

Tags: php, javascript, html, datepicker

Есть следующий код:

```
<form class="form-horizontal input_mask" action="action.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="form-control datep" id="calendar">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>December 29, 2015 - January 28, 2016</span> <b class="caret"></b>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Нужно получить в файле action.php две даты из этого календаря, чтобы в дальнейшем с ними работать. Пока с таким не работал, нет тега input (вместо него - тег i).
Прошу помощи, жду ответов

Comment: добавьте скрытый инпут, и записывайте значение туда.

Comment: Я пробовал (конечно, по-своему), но не получилось. Как мне именно записать в инпут значение?

Comment: Или же при добавлении скрытой формы она не работала (не читала значение), или ломался дизайн календаря

Comment: Не получается добавить скрытый input.

Comment: вам надо `<input type="hidden" name="dt" id="dt">` добавить в форму. далее при выборе даты в календаре заполнить  это поле. со стороны пхп получить через `$_POST['dt']`. Как заполнить поле при выборе - надо посмотреть документацию к тому календарю, который используете. Обычно для этого существует событие, которое и надо обработать.